# Android Images are not displayed after release build or if i instant run turn off

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-drawable, android-proguard, android-instant-run

I am getting images id from drawable-hdpi at run time using **getIdentifier** method using following code

```
mContext.getResources().getIdentifier(mContext.getPackageName() + ":drawable/" +  mCur.getString(mCur.getColumnIndex(Constant.COLUMN_IMAGE_DRAWABLE)), null, null)
```

i also tried following ways

```
mContext.getResources().getIdentifier(mCur.getString(mCur.getColumnIndex(Constant.COLUMN_IMAGE_DRAWABLE))+"", "drawable", mContext.getPackageName());
```

and set image resource using following code

```
imgPosotion.setImageResource(item.getDrawable());
```

both work when i turn on instant run from android studio but unfortunately none of them work when i am turn off instant run feature from android studio.
I am using Proguard at debug as well as release time using following code

```
 release {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
```

**Observed scenario**
Image are not showing. Code run perfect and showing images when run with instant run.
i make release build and then decompile it, i observed that images(.png extension) are there in res/drawable-hdpi folder but sizes are converted into 1*1 dimension(67byte) and when i tried to open just a dot are visible and when i tried to open jpg(converted to 0byte size) files they are not opened.

**Expected scenario**
Image must be visible
**Action taken to solved**
Make the image size small
convert images into from .png to jpg
I stuck to this problem so please help me. Appreciate, if anyone can help to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

nobody takes this question seriously but after do lots of type stuff i got the solution. Actually problem was with proguard, i don't known why but it works after set **false to shrinkResources**

```
release {
            ..
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources false

        }
```

Comment: You the MVP, android studio misteries

Comment: I have also. But don't want to set false. How to solve this one?

Comment: @Sakthi, You should use "keep resources" as described here https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#keep-resources

Comment: The answer from @Sakthi is the correct one. Thanks.

Comment: This solution doesn't work in my raw folder which contains mp3, Any suggestion in my case?

Answer (score 3):

It`s the bad practce, you should use official google strategy as described here https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#keep-resources

Answer (score -1):

release {
..
minifyEnabled true
shrinkResources false

```
    }
```

worked fr me